# How to distribute styles with packages?

Tags: packages, style, stylesheet

I want to define some named styles with `StyleData` and `StyleDefinitions` that are either entirely new or inherit from default stylesheets and use these named styles across my package. These include styles for displaying objects introduced by the package, styles for package documentation, etc. Needless to say, I want these styles to work seamlessly in other environments when I distribute the package.

1. Where should I put style definitions within my package? How should I organize styles?
2. What is the scope of these styles? Are they only available when the
   package is loadad?
3. What are some guidelines to define distributed styles as general as possible, considering for example that users might use different stylesheets or environments.

For example I cannot specify a text color explicitly in my style, like `FontColor -> Black`, as it won't be visible in case a user relies on the `ReverseColor` stylesheet. Leaving the color undefined causes most styles to switch color in case background (and stylesheet) is switched. How can I define styles *with colors* that are aware of the background/stylesheet, without programmatically modifying global stylesheets at the user's machine?

Comment: Put it in a `Stylesheets` folder and add `{"FrontEnd"}` to the `"Extensions"` in the `PacletInfo.m`. Read up on `PacletInfo.m` as it'll explain everything. Keep in mind that this only allows you to change _your_ stylesheets, but just have your user use your stylesheets that come with the package. I do this to handle really complex front-end stuff like [this IDE plugin](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1655203) (keep in mind that specific post is old and the IDE has had some major performance and appearance updates since).

Comment: @b3m2a1 So this only works if the user *manually* sets the stylesheet, distributed with my package? Is there really no simpler method?

Comment: do you want to hijack their system? What’s your goal here? In general, yes, to use package specific styles they need to select your style sheet from the stylesheet menu. If you set the package up correctly your stylesheet will be accessible from there.

Comment: Usually that's coupled with some amount of auto-generated notebooks with the stylesheet you care about. Like you say you have package documentation, so your package documentation should just use your stylesheet. Or your various different color schemes can be toggled by some kind of UI element that swaps out the stylesheet. At the end of the day, styles in Mathematica are always bound to a stylesheet and unless you're going to hack the user's system you can't override the stylesheets that are already there. So you need to make your own stylesheets.

Comment: @b3m2a1 No hijacking of course. I don't even want the user to have to choose my stylesheet -- that seems utterly unnecessary, as most users hate this kind of fiddling with a downloaded package. What I want is that if I define a named style, it becomes active when the package is loaded. I imagine this as any public package-function works that gets externalized. But I can even live with styles being private to the package, so user cannot access it. I have the uneasy feeling that styles do not work like functions, context-wise. One wonders, why not.

Comment: No way to do that. Styles are part of the Mathematica front-end. Packages are part of the kernel. The paclet system has some extension mechanisms to bridge the gap, but they're still separate objects. And in any case, there's no concept of a global "style". Styles are attached to stylesheets. That's all there is to it. There's some amount of object-specific styling you can apply, but that requires hardcoding all settings into your object. Anyhow, if you're going to ask your user to load your package you can ask them to use your stylesheet. It'll be right there in the menu for them to choose.

Comment: If you have a bunch of UI elements, then invert the way it works. Have the stylesheet load the package, not the package load the stylesheet. That's the way I do it in UI heavy packages. Or I have my functions create a notebook with the stylesheet already set. That's also an easy solution. There are lots of easy solutions for you to pick from, but it sounds like you want something that isn't even necessarily compatible with the system as designed.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Ok, that made it clear thank you! But it also strengthened my aversion toward stylesheets. Though I myself heavily rely on them, I cannot expect a user to load a different stylesheet every time a different package is loaded (assuming all have their own stylesheets). With object-specific, package coded styles I lose the option to have styles that behave differently in different environments. E.g. I cannot effectively check programmatically all the time if the background behind my custom object is white or black. Ok, let me retreat to think over the whole issue one more time.

Comment: You can try do that via some FE programming, e.g. something like ``FontColor->FEPrivate`If[FEPrivate`SameQ[FrontEnd`CurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], Background], Black], White, Black]`` but I wouldn't worry about that kind of thing too much. If you want a white background just put your object on a white background where you need it. It's good to try to do stuff automagically for your users, but I'd say not worth expending tons of energy on. Automagic is fragile, so go for less magical, but still aesthetically pleasing solutions, I'd say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98665/discussion-between-istvan-zachar-and-b3m2a1).